# Shared connection to server failed (trying to run an Ansible playbook)

Tags: ssh, server, ansible

I am quite new to SSH servers and Ansible so this might be a dumb question.

Tried to run an Ansible playbook whilst accessing the server with a private key using the bash command below.

```
ansible-playbook dbserv.yml -i hosts --limit local-servers --private-key=(where I put the private key)
```

However, I am getting this error:

> fatal: [xxx]: FAILED! => {
>       "changed": false, 
>       "failed": true, 
>       "invocation": {
>           "module_name": "setup"
>       }, 
>       "module_stderr": "Shared connection to xxx closed.\r\n", 
>       "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python2.7: not found\r\n", 
>       "msg": "MODULE FAILURE" }

I have Python installed on my computer so I do not understand why I am getting this error.

OS environment:
Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: Please add the information about your target OS version and the contents of `dbserv.yml` and `hosts` to your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error message you get is:

> /usr/bin/python2.7: not found

Ansible requires the **target machine** to have Python installed in order to work properly (see [Managed node requirements](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements)).

The most likely reason is that your target is Ubuntu 16.04 which does not come with Python 2 installed. In this case you need to install it or try the [experimental support for Python 3](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/python_3_support.html).

If Python 2.7 is installed in a different directory, you can add a host variable, for example in your inventory file (assuming the hostname is `xxx` as in your question`):

```
xxx ansible_python_interpreter=/path/to/python2.7
```

To run modules with Python 3 ([experimental](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/python_3_support.html#testing-python-3-module-support)), set:

```
xxx ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

---

Note: Ansible by default looks for `/usr/bin/python`, so it's likely that your playbook, inventory file, or `ansible.cfg` already contain settings for `/usr/bin/python2.7` which does not exist on the target machine.

Comment: I see. Used the command "whereis python 2.7" at the target machine and it was in /usr/bin/python2.7. 
Am I supposed to run the ansible command from the target machine??

Comment: It's unlikely that there is a Python in `/usr/bin/python2.7` if operating system says to Ansible it's not there. If you just type `/usr/bin/python2.7` - will it run? Also, 2.7 shouldn't actually be requested by default by Ansible - check your playbook, `ansible.cfg`, and inventory file.

Comment: thank you, it was an error on my side, the python 2.7 is actually in /usr/lib/python2.7
but now I have a different error saying that I do not have permission to access the python interpreter..(I've included the private key for the VM in the command)

Comment: @sabrinazuraimi There is no Python interpreter in `/usr/lib/python2.7`. It's a directory containing libraries. Most likely you don't have it inhaled.

Comment: You were right. Installed python using the command 
"sudo apt-get install python-pip" and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: i know python is not preinstalled so it has this error. but how can i install python using ansible ?  now my ping module to it still doesn't go through

Comment: @GabrielWu You can do it using `raw` module. There are multiple questions and answers on SO about this. Use the search function.

Comment: For me the solution was to run "sudo apt-get install python-pip" as advised by @sabrinazuraimi